# ASP.NET MVC - Typesafe Html.TextBoxFor with different outputmodel

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My view uses ModelX to render my HTML form and my controller action takes ModelY as input when saving the form. It seems the typesafe textbox API assumes I am using the same model in both places.

Is it possible to use different models and beeing type safe without creating my own helpers ?

`<% = Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Text) %>`

I would like something like this. Does it exist ?

```
<% = Html.TextBoxFor<InputModel,OutputModel>(input=>input.Text, output=>output.SomeOtherText)
```

Answer (score 13):

I have found a solution which involves creating a new html helper.  The OP is correct in saying that it is sometimes inappropriate to use the same class as a parameter for the action method as well as the viewpage.  Sometimes we want to pass MORE information to the ViewPage than what the user gives back to us in the form post.

The solution I came up with is to use a HtmlHelper extension method, which I called HtmlHelperFor(T obj) which I use as below:

```
<% var productForm = Html.HtmlHelperFor(Model.Product); %>
```

and then I use it as below:

```
<%= productForm.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name) %>
```

The extension method is below:

```
public static HtmlHelper<T> HtmlHelperFor<T>(this HtmlHelper html, T model)
{
    var newViewData = new ViewDataDictionary(html.ViewDataContainer.ViewData) { Model = model };
    ViewContext newViewContext = new ViewContext(html.ViewContext.Controller.ControllerContext, html.ViewContext.View, newViewData, html.ViewContext.TempData, html.ViewContext.Writer);
    var viewDataContainer = new ViewDataContainer(newViewContext.ViewData);
    return new HtmlHelper<T>(newViewContext, viewDataContainer, html.RouteCollection);
}
```

The ViewDataContainer is an implementation of the IViewDataContainer interface found in Sysetm.Web.Mvc:

```
public class ViewDataContainer : System.Web.Mvc.IViewDataContainer
{
    public ViewDataContainer(System.Web.Mvc.ViewDataDictionary viewData)
    {
        ViewData = viewData;
    }

    public System.Web.Mvc.ViewDataDictionary ViewData { get; set; }
}
```

the above calls will allow you to have a `Product` object as part of the parameters of the method that accepts the POST, instead of a class which contains project which you would normally pass to your view.

Comment: Thanks for showing your solution! I'm thinking of expanding on the idea by creating something like a `ScopedMvcForm`, and a corresponding helper `BeginScopedForm`. I would like to be able to write:

`using(var form = BeginScopedForm(Model.Product)) { form.TextBoxFor(...) }`

Comment: I would upvote this a bunch of times if I could. Not only does it answer a direct question I had (how to do the same operation the question describes but for `DisplayNameFor` calls), but it also provides a good window on how a HtmlHelper gets created and how to create one given an existing view.

Comment: @TahirHassan how can we do same for ASP.NET Core ?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to use different models and beeing type safe without creating my own helpers ?

Only by using inheritance. So you will have base model with all the properties.

Consider [XForms](http://www.codeplex.com/mvcxforms).
But I don't really understand the purpose of InputModel and OutputModel in the sample.

Comment: How about some examples in XForms that applies to his case.

Comment: Can you give a **real** sample of what you want to do? I don't really understand what you are trying to achieve (Input and Output model?).

Comment: Dmitriy Nagirnyak:

The idea is that you use one model to populate the view. You might not use the same model to save data from the view. They are to different concerns.

Comment: I often have different models for view and as input parameter for action. But I still don't need input model in the view. Your view should use **view model** and not input model.  If they are similar than you can use inheritance, aggregation or just same model for view and input (in simple cases).  Additionally what output do you expect from the sample you provided? Can you give a real sample?